# Wix Installer ExecuteSqlStrings Custom Action Order

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

As part of a .msi package created I am creating via WIX, I am copying over a db backup and attempting to restore it via the sql script extension. By the time the ExecuteSqlStrings action occurs the backup file has not been copied over yet because. I have placed both the InstallSqlData and ExecuteSqlStrings to occur right before the InstallFinalize. Is there a way to ensure that the execution the sql scripts occurs after the files have been copied? What am I missing, the installexecutesequence should execute in order right? These actions occur synchronously right?

Before someone questions the query please know that when I place the file in the location being used by the query the msi package does not error. I have also ensured that the file copies to the correct location by removing the sql script altogether. Here is some code:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="createDB_FromBackup" SourceFile="DBScript\1_Create_From_Backup.sql" />
    <ComponentGroup Id="DatabaseComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
      <Component Id="cmpSqlDatabase" Guid="{F950605D-AA59-43E6-AB19-9452F6BEC649}" KeyPath="yes" Win64="$(var.Win64)" >
        <sql:SqlDatabase 
          Id="sqlDatabase_MyDatabase"
                        Server="[ComputerName]"
                        Instance="$(var.SqlInstanceName)"
                        Database="master"
                        CreateOnInstall="no"
                        DropOnUninstall="no"
                        ContinueOnError="no"
                        ConfirmOverwrite="yes"
                        DropOnReinstall="no" 
                        DropOnInstall="no" 
                        CreateOnReinstall="no" 
                        CreateOnUninstall="no">
          <sql:SqlString Id="create_dbBackupTable"
                        ExecuteOnInstall="yes"
                        ExecuteOnReinstall="no"
                        ExecuteOnUninstall="no"
                        ContinueOnError="no"
                        Sequence="1"
                        SQL="
                        if OBJECT_ID('master.dbo._pj15DBBackupInfo') is not null 
                        begin
                            drop table master.dbo._pj15DBBackupInfo 
                        end
                        select * into master.dbo._pj15DBBackupInfo from (select BackupLocation = '[INSTALLFOLDER]DB-Backup\') dvt;" />
          <!-- restore PJ15 DB database -->
          <sql:SqlScript Id="sqlScript_CreateDB" BinaryKey="createDB_FromBackup"
                        Sequence="2"
                        ExecuteOnInstall="yes"                         
                        ExecuteOnReinstall="no"
                        ExecuteOnUninstall="no" 
                        ContinueOnError="no" />
        </sql:SqlDatabase>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom After="InstallFinalize"  Action="InstallSqlData" Overridable="no"/>
      <Custom After="InstallSqlData"  Action="ExecuteSqlStrings" Overridable="no"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Try running the script after InstallFiles action. 
<Custom After="InstallFiles"  Action="InstallSqlData" Overridable="no"/>



Reference for standard installer actions :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/suggested-installexecutesequence

Comment: @AshishKamat thanks, that seems to have solved the problem as I was able to utilize the link you provided to gain more control of the actions.